# Flutter - How to make a text tidier

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to make the text tidier, like it change to the center like picture below:

[image]

Does anyone know how?

Comment: you want to same design as per image?

Comment: yes, just like the image

Comment: @BilboBaggins Are you using on text widget or use two in column?

Comment: I use a text widget, like this => Text('Rainy days. \nUse umbrella')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you by `tidier` means make text center, you can use `textAlign`:

```
Text(
  'Are you sure want to delete ...',
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

Comment: @BilboBaggins was it what you want?